# Open ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS screen for specific Android App

Tags: android, security, permissions

I want `ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS` for my app locker Android application without 2 steps navigation. I mean can I get it in background like media permissions or direct access to my app `ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS` screen?

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 2):

After digging around in the source code of the Android settings app I think that this is not possible. The screenshot you posted is the [UsageAccessDetails](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings.git/+/master/src/com/android/settings/applications/UsageAccessDetails.java) Fragment and the only place where it gets created is on line 610 in the ManageApplication class right [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings.git/+/master/src/com/android/settings/applications/ManageApplications.java#610), which in turn is in a method that only gets invoked by the onItemClick method of the ManageApplication class right [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings.git/+/master/src/com/android/settings/applications/ManageApplications.java#749). So I think that the UsageAccessDetails Fragment only gets created when a user actually clicks on the app in the UsageAccessSettingsActivity of the Settings app.